# No web processes running error - Deploying Go container on Heroku

Tags: docker, go, heroku

I have a docker container that runs perfectly when I build and run it in the local environment. But somehow when I deploy it to Heroku with container registry I get `error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=POST path="/" host=mighty-river-17352.herokuapp.com request_id=e00ac035-9ba7-4127-a1c2-e72b718d9635 fwd="85.153.236.42" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https` in the logs.

my file structure:

[image]

Dockerfile:

[image]

Main.go:

```
func main() {

    port := os.Getenv("PORT")

    http.HandleFunc("/", HelloServer)
    log.Printf("Server started at port %s ", port)
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":"+port, nil))

}
```

Comment: have you check port ?

Comment: @ManjeetThakur hi, what exactly should I check?

Comment: Your docker container exposes the fixed 8080 port, yet your app starts on the port specified by the `PORT` env var.

Comment: @icza I removed it but the problem still exists, I doubt Heroku is not starting the container with port env variable I don't know how to solve it

Comment: try with const like `port = 8080` and after that, you need to check `os.Getenv("PORT")`

Comment: How do you build and push the image to Heroku?

Comment: @BeppeC using Heroku CLI